# parseInt: invalid int "0"

Tags: java, int, parseint

Whenever I want to parse the string `"0"` in Java to `0` (int) it throws  a InvalidInt-Error.
<s>However strings like `"1"`, `"2"` etc. work.</s>

**UPDATE:** Other numbers don't work as well.

I'm fetching the HTML source code of a PHP-File from my web page and this web page only displays one number.

Code:

```
String[] result = sourceCode.trim().split("<br>");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    result[i] = result[i].trim().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
}

    if (Integer.parseInt(result[0]) > 0) 
    {
         //Do Something
    }
```

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the information provided in the comments below the question, it turns out that you have the [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) repeatedly at the beginning of your String. You can do the following to remove it:

```
final String ZERO_WIDTH_NO_BREAK_SPACE = "\uFEFF";
String good = result[0].replace(ZERO_WIDTH_NO_BREAK_SPACE, "");
```

---

Also, there is one `TAB` hidden inbetween all those characters. Get rid of it with

```
good = good.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: But if the value really is `"1"` with some extra spaces either side, this won't do anything that the call to `trim` doesn't do.

Comment: By the way, it may be relevant that U+FEFF is the Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM), used for indicating the byte order of UTF-16 or UTF-32 text, and sometimes for indicating the encoding of other Unicode-encoded text.

Comment: That is correct, but doesn't apply in this case (as it is repeated about 15 times)